# JSDocでnamespaceのaliasを設定した際に、その名前空間に属する要素を出力する方法について

Tags: javascript

JSDocを使用しており、下記コードのようにnamespaceにaliasを設定してドキュメントを出力しようとしたのですが、clazzが名前空間に属さないことになっている上、methodに至っては出力されない状態となってしまっています。
clazzやmethodのどちらも@memberofを設定すれば正しく出力はされますが、それではaliasを設定している意味がないかと思いまして、どのように改善すれば良いかご教授お願いできますと幸いです。

```
/**
 * @namespace
 */
var longerlongerlonger = {};

/**
 * @alias longerlongerlonger
 */
var ns = longerlongerlonger;

/**
 * class1
 * @constructor clazz
 */
ns.clazz = function() {}

/**
 * method1
 */
ns.clazz.prototype.method = function() {}
```

ドキュメントに出力するのはnpmでJSDocをインストールし、下記コマンドで実行しています。
`jsdoc -r .`